# How to redirect in Symfony on kernel.controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, translation

I have a lot of XxxTestController classes which all extend a TestController class, where the test sequence (intro, start, finish test) is done. This works great.

But now I have a new test called (e.g.) EnglishTest which **must be taken** in english and is only available on the `/en/englishTest` URL. How can I redirect a spanish user who visits the test by default on `/es/englishTest` to the english version of the test?

I know `kernel.controller` and `kernel.request` events. But when I `EventSubscribe` for `kernel.request` event the Controller is not yet determined, so I don't know if a redirect is required.
And when I `EventSubscribe` to `kernel.controller` event, I can not change the response anywhere.

I do not want to write a check in each controller action, because there are many tests. What are my other options? How can I solve this with symfony?

EDIT:

@Robert I do not have a kernel.controller nor kernel.request Subscriber yet. I tried both but deleted them again as it did not solve my problem.

@Liora
Routing looks somehow like this in **BaseBundle**:

```
testsDirectory:
  path: /{_locale}/langTest
  resource: '@SurveyBundle/Resources/config/routing'
  type:     directory
  defaults:
    _locale: es|en|pt|de|pl
```

And later in **SurveyBundle**

```
englishTestIntro:
    path: /englishIntro
    defaults:
        _controller: 'SurveyBundle:EnglishTestController:intro'
englishTest:
    path: /english
    defaults:
        _controller: 'SurveyBundle:EnglishTestController:start'
englishTestFinish:
    path: /englishFinish
    defaults:
        _controller: 'SurveyBundle:EnglishTestController:finish'
```

The EnglishTestController extends TestController as many other Tests in SurveyBundle. Sometimes actions from TestController are overridden in Child controllers, because of different ways to gather and preprocess test results before persisting/progressing.

I need to make sure, when a user started an english only test at `/en/langTest/english` and he manipulates the URL to `/es/langTest/english` that a redirect will occour to english language again. And I do not want to put an if condition in every controlelr action, as there are 6 language restricted tests (by now). I'm looking for a generic solution.

Comment: can you add your kernel.controller

Comment: can you also add you routing?

Comment: Why not have a single LanguageTestController with a single action (let's say languageTestAction()) loading or redirecting dynamically (based on language) to differents tests/templates ?

Your URLs would become /en/languageTest, /es/languageTest and so on..

Would be much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Might be overthinking this.  A controller listener can't return a response but it can return a different controller action.  An action that redirects.

Comment: Thanks @cerad. I was able to set a `RedirectResponse`  to the `$event->setController` function.